# can a PHP $_SESSION survive a website crash

Tags: php, session, cookies, shopping-cart

I know this is a really vague question, but I was wondering how much a $_SESSION variable can handle in terms of stress. If a $_SESSION is like a cookie, then once a user clears his or her cookies from the browser then the $_SESSION should be destroyed. Also, if session_destroy() is called then the $_SESSION variable will be destroyed.

**Are there other instances where a $_SESSION variable can be destroyed, like maybe a website crash?** If PHP is overloaded on a website, does it directly have to affect the $_SESSION or any other functions and variables dealing with it, or does it affect everything as a whole?

**Why am I asking?** 
I'm almost finished writing an abandoned cart script for my ecommerce site and I wanted to redirect the customers back to the site where their order will still be saved in a $_SESSION. The only way the $_SESSION can be destroyed is if the customer completes the purchase. Of course, the customer can also clear the cookies on his or her browser.

But I'm wondering if there is another instance where the $_SESSION can be destroyed aside from those two mentioned above.

A lot of abandoned cart systems store the order info into a database and include that into the email the user receives so they can see the order inside the email. Sure I can write the order into a database, but it's easier to just retain everything in a $_SESSION and have the customer return to the site with their order still in an active $_SESSION.

**What can a $_SESSION survive?**

Comment: is easier the best solution when it comes to sales?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't, unless your website crash is caused by a disk crash (default session handling is filesystem based)... but if you have registered users, the longer you hold session data (especially if they're session is "logged in") the greater the risk of that session being hijacked

Comment: @KaiQing that is a great point which is why I'm still debating. But if the $_SESSION will always be there whilst implementing the abandoned cart system for every customer, then I don't see why I shouldn't use it.

Comment: Right but a session can still expire, so even if it does persist beyond a crash you still have a possibility of losing it. Personally, I would probably go with session as well since abandoned carts don't typically resume if they aren't resumed within like a day or so. Each owner has their own idea of how long a cart should live if no activity is registered. I'd give it 2 hours.

Comment: @KaiQing Of course I'm not going to have the SESSION live forever. I was thinking of allowing the SESSION to live for a month and continue to send emails at certain times until the customer buys something or the month is over.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are usually stored on the disk, in the directory defined by `session.save_path` (usually `/tmp`).

When the PHP process is loaded and you run `session_start()`, the session is restored from the version saved on the disk. When the PHP process terminates properly (no segfaults etc.), the current state of the session is written back to the disk.

So, how big can a session get? The limitations are:

- Disk size for the serialized session object (shouldn't be a problem).
- Processing: Deserialization and serialization of huge structures eat up CPU resources.
- Memory: A huge `$_SESSION` variable uses up much space in your memory. (You may need to increase your `memory_limit`.)

There is one other important other situation (aside from the ones you mentioned) where sessions are removed, it's the *garbage collection*. Depending on how your server is set up, a background job goes through all sessions every few minutes, and removes the expired ones. Or every *x*<sup>th</sup> call to PHP triggers the GC (not going into the details, as they're irrelevant here). The default expiration time depends on your PHP version and OS vendor, but it's usually between 30 minutes and 1 hour.

If you have a shopping application, you may want to increase the expiration time for your sessions, setting an appropriate value for `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are saved to your server. Mine are located in /var/lib/php/sessions for my dev server by default. However the framework I use handles them completely differently so the actually session variables being used are located in the application folder.

These stay around even after a reboot. However using php default session in a /tmp folder on reboot all users would have to relogin.. again this depends on your OS but most/all will clean /tmp on a reboot.

check your session.save_path to make sure they are not saved in /tmp and also session.gc_maxlifetime to make sure they do not expire. If none is set it's using the php default for your system which you would have to look into.

Answer (score -1):

1. Session can be destroyed using PHP or any other server side language.
2. Session will be destroyed after being idle up to 24 minutes( default in case of PHP )
3. Session will be destroyed upon closing your browser if not using persistent cookies for session.
4. Also, sessions are usually not invalidated after a server crash. In most cases, PHP and the GC don't even know that the server crashed. If the UA sends a valid cookie and the session is found on the disk, it can be continued without problems, as suggested by lyx

Comment: These are the only instances where a $_SESSION will be destroyed?

Comment: Yes. In case of website crash, if you are restarting web server, session ids will be invalidated automatically & session will be considered as destroyed.

Comment: And what about garbage collection?

Comment: Also, sessions are usually not invalidated after a server crash. In most cases, PHP and the GC don't even know that the server crashed. If the UA sends a valid cookie and the session is found on the disk, it can be continued without problems.